# Ruby on Rails Form Validations Flash on Page Reentry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

This is a rather small thing, but rather annoying.

When I submit a blank "create account" form (bringing up form validation errors & styles) and then navigate to another page and then back to the create account page the form validation errors are still there for a half second before the page refreshes.

Is there any way to clear these validations when the page is left so that they don't reappear for a half second when the page is navigated back to?

View Code:

```
<section class="form form_create_account">
  <h2 class="form_header">Create Account</h2>

  <%= form_for(@user, url: create_account_path) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <% if @user.errors[:first_name].any? %>
    <p class="error_message"><%= @user.errors[:first_name].first %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <% if @user.errors[:last_name].any? %>
    <p class="error_message"><%= @user.errors[:last_name].first %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <% if @user.errors[:email].any? %>
    <p class="error_message"><%= @user.errors[:email].first %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <% if @user.errors[:password].any? %>
    <p class="error_message"><%= @user.errors[:password].first %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <% if @user.errors[:password_confirmation].any? %>
    <p class="error_message"><%= @user.errors[:password_confirmation].first %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>

<% end %>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes rails do it automatically, but sometimes we need to do. When working with flash give special attention on render & redirect.
When you render, you want to set flash.now, instead of the normal flash.

(Ex: flash.now[:error] = "There was a problem" with render, not flash[:error] = "There was a problem".)

If you don't, then the flash message may not show up on the page that's rendered, and it will show up on the next page that's visited.

This answer is for not showing flash[:errors]. You can refer this with hiding flash as well.

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of that distinction with flash. My problem is that when revisiting a page with form validation errors they tend to still be there for a half second or so before the form re-renders and I'm not sure how to stop that from happening.